# Visual C# SoundPlayer

Tags: c#, colors

Hello im new at C# and i want to Change the Color of a Button then play a sound and if the sound is over, then Change the text but if i Start the Program and press the Button the program is freezed and i get a sound and after the sound the color change in green... Sry for my bad english

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Frage.Text.Contains("Was ist Klein, Grün und Rund?"))
    {
        button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.GreenYellow;
        if(button1.BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.GreenYellow)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer playerwin = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            playerwin.SoundLocation = @"C:\Wer wird Behindert\winsound.wav";
            playerwin.Load();
            playerwin.Play();
            if (playerwin.IsLoadCompleted)
            {
                playerwin.PlaySync();
                Frage.Text = "Was ist besser?";
            }
        }
    }else if(Frage.Text.Contains("Was ist besser?"))
    {
        button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that `PlaySync` will lock the UI thread until the sound has been played. Does it have an async method?

Comment: Sry im very new in C# I worked in Java 1 year can you explain it better? And no i have only 1 method here and it is the button_1_Click method

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm not familiar with the SoundPlayer, so I can't help there. I'll explain what I mean though. The button click and UI update are handled by the same thread. If you block that thread (i.e. by playing sound synchronously) then the thread is blocked from doing any other work, such as rendering the UI.

Comment: Oh ok but you dont know how to fix that?

Comment: Ok thanks :D i dont know how to fix that because im not so far with c# but i will learn and maybe i will know this soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Play`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.play(v=vs.110).aspx) method will create a thread to play sound. I don't see a properties or events, so it's "fire and forget" method.

You can use [`PlaySync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync(v=vs.110).aspx), which is synhcronous and control thread lifetime yourself to know when this method is finished. Use `Task` to do so and `await` for it in event handler (mark it with `async`), then UI will not be blocked, something like (untested):

```
async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    var player = new SoundPlayer { SoundLocation = @"C:\Wer wird Behindert\winsound.wav" };
    button1.Enabled = false; // prevent clicks while sound is played
    await Task.Run(() => player.PlaySync()); // next line will execute after sound playing is finished
    button1.Enabled = true;
    Frage.Text = "Was ist besser?";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PlaySync() use the actual thread so it will block you application
If you want it to be non-blocking use Play() instead.

```
        if (playerwin.IsLoadCompleted)
        {
            playerwin.Play();
            Frage.Text = "Was ist besser?";
        }
```

More information here : [Play()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.media.soundplayer.play%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes but if i click on the Button then Frage.Text changes before playerwin() is over.

Comment: Correct, so you should be okey with Sinatr anwser ;)

Comment: You should edit the question name as its more about the SoundPlayer than the text color